# $rootscope:infdig error in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I am new to angular js and i am trying to route to a state in a spa application

since i tried the following code

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state,$cookieStore) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
       if(toState.authenticate){
           if($cookieStore.get('clientID')!=null || $cookieStore.get('profile') !=null) {
               if($cookieStore.get('profile') == 0){
                  event.preventDefault();
                   $state.transitionTo("profile");
               }
           }else{
               event.preventDefault();
               $state.transitionTo("signin");
           }
       }
    if(toState.authentication){
        if($cookieStore.get('clientID')!=null || $cookieStore.get('profile') !=null) {

        }else{
            event.preventDefault();

            $state.transitionTo("signin");
        }
    }

    if(toState.loggedin){
        if($cookieStore.get('clientID')!=null){
            event.preventDefault();



               $state.transitionTo("dashboard");
            }
        }
    });
  });
```

but ,i got this error

```
angular.js:13708
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost/spa/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:412
    at m.$digest (http://localhost/spa/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:143:281)
    at m.$apply (http://localhost/spa/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:145:401)
    at http://localhost/spa/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:20:457
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost/spa/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:41:376)
    at c (http://localhost/spa/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:20:378)
    at Bc (http://localhost/spa/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:21:163)
    at ge (http://localhost/spa/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:19:484)
    at http://localhost/spa/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:315:135
```

can any one please help me to solve this error , i tried this using `$state.go()`

but i got the same error 
please help me to solve this error or give me a routing solution ,
thanks in advance

Comment: You're attempting to hook into `$stateChangeStart` and change the state inside of that handler. Unfortunately, what's happening is that you're trying to change the state to another state which is then calling `$stateChangeStart` again, which then tries to go to that same state.... etc. infdig errors are the result of faulty logic which causes an infinite loop.

Comment: @DanPantry  sir can u suggest a logic for that